# JsonPath filter

Tags: ansible, jsonpath

I need to get all key and value `"tag_aa": "PROJECT_aa",` with JsonPath and initial words 'tag_' it is possible?

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content_language": "ca",
    "content_length": "1848",
    "content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ssh: rdp:; img-src 'self' data: https://*.tile.openstreetmap.org/ ; connect-src 'self' https://crash.host.com/ https://license.host.com/api/upload ; frame-ancestors 'self' ; base-uri 'self'; form-action 'self' javascript: 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'; worker-src 'self' blob:",
    "content_type": "application/json",
    "cookies": {},
    "cookies_string": "",
    "date": "Fri, 16 Sep 2022 12:44:24 GMT",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "etag": "\"a331268f2342b49b22adce81ffd44d9cee0e384d1ec1d506ec44656\"",
    "failed": false,
    "json": {
        "domainType": "host_config",
        "extensions": {
            "attributes": {
                "management_protocol": "none",
                "meta_data": {
                    "created_at": "2021-04-12T09:03:59.202860+00:00",
                    "created_by": "usr",
                    "updated_at": "2022-06-29T08:47:11.630478+00:00"
                },
                "tag_aa": "PROJECT_aa",
                "tag_bb": "aa_aa",
                "tag_cc": "cc_cc",
                "tag_dd": "dd_dd"
                
            },
            "cluster_nodes": null,
            "effective_attributes": null,
            "folder": "dir/",
            "is_cluster": false,
            "is_offline": false
        },
        "id": "host2",
        "links": [
            {
                "domainType": "link",
                "href": "http://1.1.1.1/host/host/api/1.0/objects/host_config/host2",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "self",
                "type": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "domainType": "link",
                "href": "http://1.1.1.1/host/host/api/1.0/objects/host_config/host2",
                "method": "PUT",
                "rel": "urn:org.restfulobjects:rels/update",
                "type": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "domainType": "link",
                "href": "http://1.1.1.1/host/host/api/1.0/objects/host_config/host2",
                "method": "DELETE",
                "rel": "urn:org.restfulobjects:rels/delete",
                "type": "application/json"
            },
            {
                "domainType": "link",
                "href": "http://1.1.1.1/host/host/api/1.0/objects/folder_config/~skyit~milan~linux~dino_legacy_pdl~calab-legacy_emmg",
                "method": "GET",
                "rel": "urn:com.host:rels/folder_config",
                "title": "The folder config of the host.",
                "type": "application/json"
            }
        ],
        "members": {},
        "title": "host2"
    },
    "msg": "OK (1848 bytes)",
    "redirected": false,
    "server": "Apache",
    "status": 200,
    "url": "http://1.1.1.1/host/host/api/v0/objects/host_config/host2",
    "x_content_type_options": "nosniff"
}
```

Comment: Ansible suports [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) expressions via the [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries) filter. Those docs should get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks larsks, i will learn them